# OnItemSelectedListener not working for spinner

Tags: android, spinner, listener

I have a spinner which I have set up using a custom ArrayAdapter:

```
    private static class CustomAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText("");
        return view;
    }
```

It is initialized as follows (the Spinner spinner; statement is up above as a class variable):

```
    this.spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    CustomAdapter<String> adapter = new CustomAdapter<String>(this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, new String[] {"Set Homepage"});

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I have implemented the OnItemSelectedListener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{...}
```

And have the required callbacks:

```
    //spinner methods
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //if (pos == 1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Person wants to change the homepage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //}
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Person wants to change the homepage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

The xml for the spinner:

```
            <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner1"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_holo_dark" />
```

The problem is, whenever an item is selected from the spinner, nothing at all happens, even after I removed all conditions as you can see above.

Comment: please put the whole class code if possible.

Comment: its almost 700 lines so yeh, im not really sure how it would help to be honest, is there something you were thinking of?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in this code. Probably is something wrong in the rest of the code/layout.

Comment: have you override getItem() and getItemId()..in CustomAdapter

Comment: I had not, but now I have and there is no difference, am I supposed to do anything other than override them, also the the other people, I have added the place where I have declared the spinner in the xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> OnItemSelectedListener not working for spinner

Because you are passing only one item in Adapter which is by default selected. Probably you are getting toast message when starting your Application.

So add more elements to check `OnItemSelectedListener` behavior.

Comment: It must be a bug that .onItemSelected is only invoked when there are more than one member in the list in the Spinner? Once I added a dummy element, the method was called as further members were dynamically included. (In case it help others)