# Spinner onItemSelected is not calling

Tags: java, android

I am using the following code in fragment's `onCreate` method.

```
spinner=(Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String [] values = {"Erkek","Kadın"};
ArrayAdapter<String> LTRadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, values);        LTRadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(LTRadapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                        Log.w("item","selected");

                       if (position == 0) {
                           spinnerTextView.setText("Erkek");
                       }else if(position == 1) {
                           spinnerTextView.setText("Kadın");
                       }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                        spinnerTextView.setText("");
                    }

                });
```

But onItemSelected method is not calling. How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: What's happening when you select second item. Or it just not going in the onItemSelected method

Comment: It is same, nothing happening

Comment: have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845424/onitemselectedlistener-not-working-for-spinner

Comment: What are the values that you passing in the adapter

Comment: See my update for values pls.